# WPF Move text "outside" the boundaries of its own element

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am making a LinearGauge control with an ItemsControl. I would like to show the boundaries labels exactly at the center of two bars. I'll try to depict my problem in the screenshot below:

[image]

Thus, the labels should all move a few pixels to the right. But the problem of course is, is that the element boundaries are where the next colored bar starts. So I want to move the label "while ignoring the element boundaries".

Is there an easy trick to do something like that?

The xaml I have so far:

```
    <ItemsControl 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HorizontalGaugeElement}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle 
                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                        Height="30" 
                        Fill="{Binding Color}">
                        <Rectangle.Width>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoundsToWidthConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Lower"/>
                                <Binding Path="Upper"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" Path="DataContext.ValueToPercentage"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" Path="DataContext.GaugeSize"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Rectangle.Width>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Visibility="{Binding ShowLowerBoundary, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                        Text="{Binding Lower}"
                        Margin="5, 0, 0, 0">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                        Text="{Binding Upper}" TextAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VerticalGaugeElement}">
                <!-- similar story but then vertical --> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding IsHorizontal, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOrientationConverter}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: try negative margin: `Margin="0, 0, -5, 0"`

Comment: Or a rendertransform translatetransform. With a positive X value.

Comment: Like a charm, thx @ASh

Comment: Like a charm, thx @Andy :). Both work perfect